# How to convert to pixels to CGFloat?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgfloat

I have an image with width as '50px' and height as '40px' in my Webpage.

Now i want to display the image with same dimensions in UIImageView.

How can i convert the pixels into CGFloat?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: 50.0 and 40.0 or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: Yes it is 50.0 and 40.0

Answer (score 2):

You can create it like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 50.0, 40.0)];

NSString *imageURL = @"www.YourURLHere.com/YourPicture.jpg";

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

The CGFloat values have a 1 to 1 relationship with pixels.

Thus 100 x 100 pixels should be CGRect of 100 x 100, example:

```
CGRect CGRectMake (
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat width,
   CGFloat height
);
```

Comment: `CGFloat(100,100)`? What is that supposed to do? Were you thinking of `CGSize(100.0, 100.0)`?

Comment: You're right! No, I was thinking of CGPointMake! changed it now.

Comment: Note that in iOS the base unit is a "point", not a pixel. A very important distinction on retina.